# Are there any Flex/AS3 multiuser multi-chatroom apps?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, chat

I need a custom multi-user multi-chatroom app to extend an existing Flex app that I have.

I obviously wouldn't like to develop it from scratch, but focus only on the customizations and integration.

Are there any products (free or commercial) that provide multi-chatroom functionality from which I could start?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/services/collaboration.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **Union Platform** chat tutorial:
http://www.unionplatform.com/?page_id=1216

You can also check **BlazeDS** chat example:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=build_apps_3.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an [AS3 Chat Application](http://www.kongregate.com/games/UnknownGuardian/game-development-room-gdr) that makes use of [Player.io](http://playerio.com/)'s free server package of 20 gigs of data transfer, other small limitations. The app is open source, and you can find [the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/UnknownGuardian/GameDevelopmentRoom).

The chat itself only uses one room, since it is averaging only around 10-15 users on at any time and its specialized to helping flash game developers, meaning it has a code storage area (simple database interaction), developer links, actionscript help, etc, but it does have some basic features if you want to see how I code them.

The chat itself has a few features you might be interested in checking out even if you don't use the source code, are such:

- Support for authentication on server-side
- Different types of users. (Currently overlord admin, admin, mod, developer, regular users)
- Editable individual user data (Currently saves how long each user has spent on the app)
- Server-side Silencing and banning individual users
- Support for tags near usernames
- Sound Settings on message received
- Code box for users to share large amounts of text without spamming the chat
- Support for multiple rooms (uses 1 public currently + 1 hidden for select users)

The server-side is written in C# and hosted on playerio.com and is supposed to be an authoritative server (meaning it checks all the client data and makes sure its valid before doing anything). The server code is also included on github.

If your interested you can comment and I will answer any questions.